# how to use where caluse on primary key?

Tags: mysql

i'm developing a quiz website. In my database, I need a table which shows 
reported quiz errors. It should look like this:

```
______________________________________________________________________
|key|    quiz_number |     who_reported_this_error | reported_number  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------       
| 1 |        5       | goid482,saiai10,hahakaka    |         3        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2 |        3       | fiiai55,kihogi84            |         1        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If a user named hanabi reported an error about quiz number 5,
first I need to check the `who_reported_this_error` column because
I don't want for a user to report same error twice. If the user 'hanabi' doesn't exist in "who_reported_this_error" column I should update row 1.

Now for my problem. I want to find a row which I should update with a key column, and the key column's number should automatically increased. But I know that I can't use a WHERE clause on this primary key. Hhow can I solve this problem?

Comment: multi-value columns like `who_reported_this_error` are tragically **fundamental mistake** in every case! You need to do research on what data normalization is, and the you would not have made this design error and would not be asking this question.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the table schema. **NEVER** store comma-separated data in a single column. You should structure the table to look more like this:

```
____________________________________________
|key| quiz_number | who_reported_this_error |
────────────────────────────────────────────
| 1 |      5      | goid482                 |
---------------------------------------------
| 2 |      3      | fiiai55                 |
---------------------------------------------
| 3 |      5      | saiai10                 |
---------------------------------------------
| 4 |      5      | hahakaka                |
---------------------------------------------
| 5 |      3      | kihogi84                |
--------------------------------------------
```

You might also want a timestamp column on this table. Then, put a UNIQUE constraint on the `quiz_number` and `who_reported_this_error` columns to prevent the duplicates.

If you later need to see everyone who reported errors for quiz 5 in the same record, use MySql's `group_concat()` function to build that information on the fly. Just don't store the data that way.

The `key` column has nothing to do with this question. You certainly can use your primary key in a WHERE clause. It just won't help you in this case because that data isn't relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: Does it down the speed of my database?

Comment: No, it makes it faster, because now you can index the columns properly.

Comment: okay thanks i think i should restructure my table